# Действия с QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, sql, qt, viewmodel

Я при помощи запроса получаю некую выборку. Я её закидываю в `QSqlTableModel`.
И тут мне захотелось сделать некие действия перед тем, как я добавлю модель в `QTableView`.

А именно:

1. Разукрасить некоторые строки с определенными данными.
2. Объединить ячейки с одинаковыми значениями по вертикали в некоторых строках.
3. Подсчитать в некоторых столбцах сумму и добавить её в некоторый столбец, который я создам.

Как я думал, копать можно в сторону `QProxyModel`, но он уже устаревший, если верить документации. Тогда я нашел некий `QAbstractProxyModel`(хоть он и показался мне слегка "голым"). 
Но есть пару нюансов. 
Я не нашел методов для объединения ячеек (типa setSpan какого-то), может плохо искал. Цвет строки можно вроде через

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole)
```

Столбцы добавлять через

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::insertRow(int row, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())
```

Хороший ли способ использовать `QAbstractProxyModel` для моих целей?

**upd** В идеале всё должно быть, как на картинке. Нарисовал в экселе, как я хочу это видеть в `QTableView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**upd2** переопределил QSqlTableModel. Вот метод data (может, кому-то тоже придется с таким работать)

```
QVariant MTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
    {
        if (!QSqlTableModel::data(this->index(idx.row(), 1)).toString().isEmpty())
        {
            QVariant v = QColor(200, 200, 200, 150);
            return v;
        }
    }
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return QSqlTableModel::data(idx);
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`QAbstractProxyModel` - именно то, что вам нужно. Чтобы раскрасить некоторые ячейки, нужно в методе `data` обрабатывать роль [Qt::BackgroundRole](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum). Когда представление запрашивает эту роль, нужно вернуть цвет в виде `QVariant`.

> Подсчитать сумму в некоторых столбцах и добавить её в некоторый столбец...

Может быть, в последнюю строку? Не представляю, как это будет выглядеть в столбце. Но вообще для этого в методе `rowCount` возвращайте значение `rowCount` исходной модели + 1. А в методе `data` проверяйте: если запрошена последняя строка, то возвращайте сумму ячеек. Всё это может выглядеть так (псевдокод):

```
int MyModel::rowCount(QModelIndex parent)
{
    return sourceModel.rowCount() + 1;    
}

QVariant MyModel::data(QModelIndex index, int role)
{
    if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
    {
        if (index.row() % 2 == 0)
            return QVariant(Qt::white);
        else return QVariant(Qt::black);
    }
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        if (index.row() < rowCount() - 1)
        {
            return sourceModel.data(index, role);
        }
        else
        {
            return sum(index.column);   //Напишите эту функцию сами
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

Что касается объединения ячеек - тут всё сложнее. У `QTableView` есть метод [QTableView::setSpan](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSpan), но он никак не работает с моделями. Тут я не могу подсказать, как правильно сделать. Возможно, [этот ресурс](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/43611-How-to-use-setSpan-in-QTableView) поможет вам найти решение.

---

Понял. В таком случае методы количества строк и столбцов будут выглядеть так:

```
int MyModel::rowCount(QModelIndex parent)
{
    return sourceModel.rowCount();    
}
int MyModel::columnCount(QModelIndex parent)
{
    return sourceModel.columnCount() + 1;    
}
```

В методе `data` нужно проверять, какой столбец запрошен. Если это столбец №2, то возвращать сумму строки. Если любой другой - возвращать соответствующее значение исходной модели.

Comment: Все же нужно, чтобы сумма была в столбце. У меня есть в трех столбцах числа, нужно в конце писать их сумму. Хотя, я это лучше перепишу в отчетах. Так же я, наверное, сделаю и с объединениями ячеек. Спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: @DesmondFox, Можете нарисовать, как это должно выглядеть? Я себе представляю это так: внизу таблицы добавляется одна строка, в каждой ячейке которой находится сумма соответствующего столбца.

Comment: Обновил шапку. Думаю, нормально нарисовал

Comment: Я всё же подумал, что может быть лишним для "рабочей" таблицы. Всё же этим "Суммам" нужно быть в отчете по таблице. Осталось только цвет строки поменять. Пока изучаю работу `QAbstractProxyModel`, т.к. совсем не понимаю, что там происходит.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли. Есть ли какая-то небольшая вводная статья по своим моделям? Ибо разобраться что-то не могу

Comment: Может, если мне тогда нужно только цвет поменять в строках, то просто переопределить `QSqlTableModel`?

Comment: @DesmondFox, да, можно переопределить QSqlTableModel. Насчёт статьи не знаю - я изучал только по документации.

Comment: да, я переопределил QSqlTableModel. Пока полет нормальный. Остальное, что я хотел, лучше закину в отчет по таблице.  Как я переопределил, я написал в шапке. Мало ли, может кому-то понадобится